# Run ffmpeg on Ubuntu every 1 minute

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-streaming

What is the best way to run ffmpeg on Ubuntu every 1 minute - to run it I use this command:

```
/bin/ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp -i 'rtsp://admin:password@hostname.com:500/Streaming/Channels/101/' -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)' -vf scale=1920:1080 -reorder_queue_size 4000 -max_delay 10000000 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 2500k -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -f flv 'rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/FB-key'
```

I tried the watch command but I receive sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected.

The reason to run it every 1 minute is because ffmpeg fails quite often and I want to use it for longer streaming times.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 - in a desired folder I created a bash file in command line:

`touch streaming.sh`

I ran `chmod u+x streaming.sh` to make it executable.

I edited the file with a text editor and inserted:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp -i 'rtsp://admin:password@hostname.com:500/Streaming/Channels/101/' -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)' -vf scale=1920:1080 -reorder_queue_size 4000 -max_delay 10000000 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 2500k -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -f flv 'rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/FB-key'
```

I saved the file and in the command line, inside the desired folder, I ran the command `watch -n 60 ./streaming.sh` - to run it every 60 seconds. ffmpeg ran fine, and the streaming was successful.